# "Import" into Rust and then use a Python dict

Tags: rust, pyo3

When I say "import" I mean "pass as a parameter" to a `pyfunction` in a Rust module.

My function in Python looks like this:

```py
index_ops.update_index(PATH_STR, INDEX_NAME, hits)
```

The first two parameters are Strings, the second is a list of `dict`s. These `dict`s may or may not all have the same keys and value types. The key "_source" in each `dict` has a value which is itself a `dict`. I appreciate that it may make life easier if each `dict` has identical keys and value types.

This is the kind of thing I've tried so far:

```
use pyo3::types::IntoPyDict;

#[pyfunction]
fn update_index(py: Python, dir_root_path_str: &str, index_name: 
    &str, hits: Vec<std::collections::HashMap<String, PyObject>>) {
    for hit in hits {
        info!("hit {:?} type {}", hit, utilities::str_type_of(&hit));
        // prints this: "hit {"_score": Py(0x22e9a2a12d0), "_index": Py(0x22e961a3190), "_id": Py(0x22e9a452060), 
"_source": Py(0x22e9a4fdb80)} type std::collections::hash::map::HashMap<alloc::string::String, pyo3::instance::Py<pyo3::types::any::PyAny>>"
        let source = &hit["_source"];
        info!("source {:?} type {}", source, utilities::str_type_of(&source));
        // prints this: "source Py(0x22e9a4fdb80) type &pyo3::instance::Py<pyo3::types::any::PyAny>"

        // let dict = source.into_py_dict(&source); // doesn't compile: " the method `into_py_dict` exists for reference `&Py<PyAny>`, 
but its trait bounds were not satisfied"
        ...
```

... Ideally I want to find a way of converting these `PyObject`s (if that's what they all are) into a regular Rust type.

I think I can work out how to do that if I know all the keys and value types.
But what options might I have if I don't know all the keys and value types?

Maybe there's somewhere in the documentation which teaches this kind of thing? I found [this page](https://pyo3.rs/main/function), but it's really not telling me what I need to understand. For some reason that manual seems to have more about calling Python from Rust than vice versa.

Comment: *"Ideally I want to find a way of converting these `PyObject`s into a regular Rust type"* - You may be interested in [this section](https://pyo3.rs/main/conversions/traits) of the PyO3 User Guide.

Comment: Will check out. Hopefully this comment won't be auto-deleted if I don't say "T 'anks".